# Mapping a OneToMany unidirectional relationship

Tags: java, jpa

Considering these tables as example, where each `person` can have multiple `address`es.

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE address (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    person_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

I would like to map these tables to JPA entities, but I wouldn't like to map a bidirectional relationship between them using `mappedBy`.

What's the proper way to map a `OneToMany` unidirectional relationship between `Person` and `Address`? Considering that the `Person` must know their `Address`es, but the `Address` must not know the `Person` it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using annotations JoinColumn and ManyToOne in Person Entity.

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_pkey")
public List<Address> getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make it bidirectional. You can simply place the `@OneToMany` annotation on you collection-typed field in `Person` and specify the `JoinColumn` of the `address` table.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html), Example 3. I think that's what you're looking for.

So you will have something like:

```
// In Person class:

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
public Set<Address> getAddresses() {return addresses;}
```

No `mappedBy` attribute, no bidirectional mapping.