# How to use LAZY loading for OneToMany Unidirection in JPA 2.0?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Is it possible to use `LAZY` loding in `OneToMany` unidirection mapping?
In my example, `BookShelf` have a list of `Book` as `LAZY` loading.

I need to retrieve `bookList` by `BookShelf's ID`, again.
I would like to know possible way `selet many from OneToMany unidirection mapping`.

Book.java

```
@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    ....
}
```

BookShelf.java

```
@Entity
public class BookShelf implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_SHELF_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private List<Book> bookList;
}
```

I would like to find book list by BookShelf using JPQL, not native query.

Comment: See if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864999/mapping-a-onetomany-unidirectional-relationship

Comment: @RodrigoBento thanks, I already get that, It is not like my requirement. I want to select many from `OneToMany unidirection mapping`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JOIN` table strategy. As below;

```
Query q =  em.createQuery("SELECT bs.bookList FROM BookShelf bs LEFT JOIN FETCH bs.bookList WHERE bs.id = :bookShelfId");
q.setParameter("bookShelfId", bookShelfId);
List<Book>  result = q.getResultList();
```